# Dialog Fragment doesn't appear after orientation change which should be triggered after network call

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I'm making a network call and on completion of that, there are two cases.
1. if error result - have to display dialog (Using Custom Dialog Fragment)
2. if success move to next activity

When orientation is changed during the network call, it still gives me result but the Dialog Fragment is not being displayed if error response. I can see error response in the logs.

Need help in showing the dialog fragment after we receive error response.

BTW: Success response is calling Intent and is working fine even after orientation change.

```
SampleOAuth.getUserDetails(userId, new ResultListener<Networkresponse>(){
     @Override
     public void onComplete(final NetworkResponse response){
          if(response.isError()){
              CustomDialogFragment dialogFragment = new CustomDialogFragment(response.getErrorCode(),response.getErrorMessage(),R.string.ok);
              FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
              dialogFragment.show(fragmentManager,"tag");
         } else{
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,SampleActivity.class));
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your post.

Comment: Added relevant code

Comment: Not really the relevant code I was expecting...because you have not provided any information about the method calls relative to the lifecycle.

Comment: I didn't override any lifecycle methods besides onCreate(). On button click the above stated method should happen taking the userId from edittext field. I'm not overriding any onSaveInstanceState